# Error: latestlocation.coordinate.longitude APIs deprecated as of iOS7, unavailable in Swift

Tags: swift, core-location

Trying to pull the longitude/latitude out of the CoreLocation.

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

Was trying

```
latitude.text = String(format: "%.4f", latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        latitude.text = String(format: "%.4f", latestLocation.latitude)
longitude.text = String(format: "%.4f", latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        horizontalAccuracy.text = String(format: "%.4f",
```

These won't compile giving:

"coordinate is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift."

However:

```
latestLocation.horizontalAccuracy)
        altitude.text = String(format: "%.4fm", latestLocation.altitude)
verticalAccuracy.text = String(format: "%.4f", latestLocation.verticalAccuracy)
```

do work and if I remove the "coordinate" in the latitude example:

```
latitude.text = String(format: "%.4f", latestLocation.longitude)
        latitude.text = String(format: "%.4f", latestLocation.latitude)
```

I get an EXC_BREAKPOINT barf.

Any ideas?

Comment: What type is `latestLocation`?  Show the code that sets `latestLocation`.

Comment: var latestLocation: AnyObject = locations[locations.count - 1]

Comment: Try `var latestLocation = locations[locations.count - 1] as! CLLocation`.  By the way, `latitude.text` is being set to `longitude` in some of the code shown.

Comment: That works, could you explain why. The irony was this is a piece of test code that I'd taken from Neil Smyth's  "iOS 8 App Development" book and worked in the original form. Many thanks.